# DOCTOR WHO: Davros in The Stolen Earth and The Magician's Apprentice

Tags: doctor-who

We all know that the Doctor did not save (first) Davros in that balt of rising hands from the dirt.

But, when Davros met the Doctor's younger versions (let's talk about The Stolen Earth Tennant era)  he did not mention anything about his younger self being left there by the Doctor.

I know that the simple out-of-universe answer to a plot hole is that it's a "scripting error", or that "in the Tennant era they couldn't know that Doctor will have the chance to save or not Davros".

Is there any other answer to this (in or out of universe)?

Comment: What makes you think Davros remembers being saved by the Doctor as a child? Even if he did, he remembers the old man (12th) and is currently dealing with an earlier incarnation in Tennant (10) during Stolen Earth. He can't possibly know they're the same person.

Comment: How Davros couldn't know that the old man was Doctor, since he saw the Tardis behind the Doctor. So, what you saying is that, Davros couldn't deal with Tennant (10) for the "not helping me when I was a child" because Doctor did not do that action yet?

Comment: As far as Davros knows, this is a different person, with the same car model (or ship, or time vessel or whatever). It wasn't until the Doctor regenerated into Capaldi that he probably put 2 and 2 together and realized they were the same man.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 2):

**The chance to save Davros hadn't "happened yet"**

Take a look at the timeline of A Christmas Carol.  The Doctor does a number of things in Kazran Sardick's past, eventually making him a nicer person.  Since they all took place in Sardick's past, they should have "always happened", but they didn't - they only "happened" as The Doctor went back to cause them to happen.

So it's only when The Doctor reaches the point in HIS timeline where he goes back and does a thing (like refusing to save a young boy) does that event retroactively occur in the timeline of those people affected.

Now they've also done moments where The Doctor meets someone for "the first time" only to realize quickly that said person has very clearly met him already - Queen Elizabeth is a good example.  And if you're looking for an explanation as to why it works one way sometimes, and another way the rest, I'll have to make something up.

Comment: Time can be re-written. With precission, with great care. The Doctor said to Clara it in the Series 8 finae, I think...A Christmas Carol is a good example of that, as is the Doctor saving Davros after he didn't.